# Parsing HTML and writing to CSV using Beautifulsoup - AttributeError or no html being parsed

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

I am either receiving an error or nothing is being parsed/written with the following code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')
userinfo = soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class": "fieldWrapper"})
rows = userinfo.find_all(attrs="value")

with open('testfile1.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerow(rows)
```

rows = userinfo.find_all(attrs="value")

AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find_all'

So I tried a for loop with print just to test it, but that returns nothing while the program runs successfully:

```
userinfo = soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class": "fieldWrapper"})
for row in userinfo:
    rows = row.find_all(attrs="value")
    print(rows)
```

This is the html I am trying to parse. I am trying to return the text from the value attributes:

```
<div class="controlHolder">
                        <div id="usernameWrapper" class="fieldWrapper">
                            <span class="styled">Username:</span>
                            <div class="theField">
                                <input name="ctl00$cleanMainPlaceHolder$tbUsername" type="text" value="username" maxlength="16" id="ctl00_cleanMainPlaceHolder_tbUsername" disabled="disabled" tabindex="1" class="textbox longTextBox">
                                <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$cleanMainPlaceHolder$hdnUserName" id="ctl00_cleanMainPlaceHolder_hdnUserName" value="AAubrey"> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="fullNameWrapper" class="fieldWrapper">
                            <span class="styled">Full Name:</span>
                            <div class="theField">
                                <input name="ctl00$cleanMainPlaceHolder$tbFullName" type="text" value="Full Name" maxlength="50" id="ctl00_cleanMainPlaceHolder_tbFullName" tabindex="2" class="textbox longTextBox">
                                <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$cleanMainPlaceHolder$hdnFullName" id="ctl00_cleanMainPlaceHolder_hdnFullName" value="Anthony Aubrey">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="emailWrapper" class="fieldWrapper">
                            <span class="styled">Email:</span>
                            <div class="theField">
                                <input name="ctl00$cleanMainPlaceHolder$tbEmail" type="text" value="email@email.com" maxlength="60" id="ctl00_cleanMainPlaceHolder_tbEmail" tabindex="3" class="textbox longTextBox">
                                <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$cleanMainPlaceHolder$hdnEmail" id="ctl00_cleanMainPlaceHolder_hdnEmail" value="aaubrey@bankatunited.com">
                                <span id="ctl00_cleanMainPlaceHolder_validateEmail" style="color:Red;display:none;">Invalid E-Mail</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="commentWrapper" class="fieldWrapper">
                            <span class="styled">Comment:</span>
                            <div class="theField">
                                <textarea name="ctl00$cleanMainPlaceHolder$tbComment" rows="2" cols="20" id="ctl00_cleanMainPlaceHolder_tbComment" tabindex="4" class="textbox longTextBox"></textarea>
                                <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$cleanMainPlaceHolder$hdnComment" id="ctl00_cleanMainPlaceHolder_hdnComment">
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first error stems from the fact that `find_all` returns a ResultSet, which is more or less a list: you would have to iterate through the elements of `userinfo` and call `find_all` on those instead.

For your second issue, I'm pretty sure when `attrs` is passed a string, it searches for elements with that string as its class. The html you provided contains no elements with class `value`, so it makes sense that nothing would get printed out. You can access an element's value with `.get('value')`

To print out the value of the text inputs, the following code should work.
(The try/except is just so the script doesn't crash if a text input isn't found)

```
for field_wrapper in soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class": "fieldWrapper"}):
    try:
        print(field_wrapper.find("input", attrs={"type": "text"}).get('value'))
    except:
        continue
```

Comment: I see what you mean, I tried using the code you provided but again it prints nothing. I am trying to get the text from value="username" value="Full Name" value="email@email.com" as I am trying to pull text from a form.

Comment: Gotcha. My edited answer above prints the expected output when I initialize BeautifulSoup with the source HTML you provided. If it still prints out nothing, its possible `browser.page_source` isn't what you expect it to be, or your parser isn't handling the page correctly.

Comment: I tried the new version you wrote and still nothing, I put `except: print('no text found')` just to see if it will print anything but still nothing, this seems strange, I think you are right, there seems to be something wrong with the page source perhaps. I am using selenium to get to this point in the code with no issues.

Comment: Hmmm, okay. Its probably a parser / soup issue then. Is `browser.page_source` a sensible value? Also, does the solution above work for you when you initialize BeautifulSoup with the sample HTML?

Comment: The solution above works great with the sample HTML, thanks a lot for that. I am using selenium to navigate the site to get to the desired page as information is required to access it. Perhaps there is some issue with the page I am pointing to. `browser.page_source` should point BeautifulSoup to the correct page but it does not seem like it is parsing from there.

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case, perhaps try posting it as a selenium question if you're still stuck? Also, I'm not 100% sure, but `browser.page_source` sounds like it would grab the HTML written by the programmer, not the HTML after the client interacts with the page.

Comment: Problem was solved. I placed `print(browser.current_url)` in different spots throughout the code to see if BeautifulSoup was getting the right information. Turns out it was not. Placing `time.sleep(2)` right after navigating to the page allowed it to fetch the right info. Thanks for your help with the code!

Comment: No problem! Glad you figured it out. :-)